# Transform arrays of objects to array of objects with jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I am having trouble dealing with arrays in JOLT.

**Input:**

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "home_phone": [
      "55555555",
      "66666666"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "home_phone": [
      "77777777",
      "88888888"
    ]
  }
]
```

**Desired output:**

```json
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "home": "55555555"
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "home": "66666666"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "home_phone": "77777777"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "home_phone": "88888888"
  }
]
```

Note that each element of the home_phone array should be matched with its correspondent id in its JSON document.

This is the spec I have drafted so far without much success:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "home_phone": {
          "*": "[].phone",
          "@(1,id)": "[].id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Eliel. I presume( as desired output suggests ) all keys other than `id` will be `home_phone` but not `home`, won't they ? Or, they just should be `phone` as your spec suggests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be using

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "home_phone": {
          "*": { // partition the objects by indexes from different two levels 
            "@2,id": "&3_&1.id",
            "@": "&3_&1.&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // add an array wrapper while getting rid of newly formed object labels
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your objects in an array of an array in one `shift` operation and then you can bring them up with just going to that level with `"*": ""` in the second `shift` operation.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "home_*": {
          "*": {
            "@(2,id)": "[&3][&1].id",
            "@0": "[&3][&1].&(2,1)"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```